# I am trying to read bytes using clientStream.Read when multiple request call at a time but getting "Operation not allowed on non-connected sockets"

Tags: c#, .net

```
byte[] messageBytes = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead = 0;
NetworkStream clientStream = _client.GetStream();
ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
bytesRead = clientStream.Read(messageBytes, 0, 8192);
string strMessage = encoder.GetString(messageBytes, 0, bytesRead);
return strMessage;
}

string strMessage = String.Empty;
while (true) {
  try {
    strMessage = await Read();
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
    //a socket error has occured
    Log.Error(e, e.Message);
    break;
  }
}
```

I am trying to read bytes using clientStream.Read() when multiple request call at a time but getting "Operation not allowed on non-connected sockets"
it is reading bytes for first request but for second or third it is not reading bytes.

Comment: What is `_client`? That error sounds like you might be trying to read from a UDP socket. Or maybe a tcp socket that is listening for incoming connections.

Comment: public void Initialize(TcpClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

Comment: So, clearly `_client.Connected == false`...

Comment: so whats should be done?

Comment: Do you have some specific reason for using a raw networkstream? Some higher level protocol like http or a message bus might be easier to use.